# Redux dev tool option does not work on Safari

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-router-redux

I have a web app with front-end is written with react and redux and this is my index.jsx file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

import App from './app/App';
import Home from './app/Home';
import ContactMe from './app/ContactMe';
import ErrorPage from './app/ErrorPage';
import Post from './app/Post';
import makeRootReducer from './reducers/index';
require('./assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss');
require('./assets/stylesheets/styles.scss');

let store = null;
const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk);

const enhancer = compose(
  middleware,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && compose
);

store = createStore(
  makeRootReducer(),
  {},
  enhancer
);

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} >
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path="contact-me" component={ContactMe} />
      <Route path="post/:id" component={Post} />
      <Route path="*" component={ErrorPage} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Currently this web app can work on chrome but not on Safari.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.apply')
```

This is the error I got from safari.
And I found that if I remove one line of code as below

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && compose
```

it works properly both on chrome and safari but I can't use redux dev tool.
If I change && to ||  (as below and it works on safari but not on chrome

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ || compose
```

Any one can figure out what wrong with my code. Because I need to use dev tool to trace the state of web app and run it on chrome and safari as well

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but [this](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/redux-monitor/id1575132553) might help.

Answer (score 4):

I was running into the same issue for quite some time, but I was ignoring it. The most annoying part is that you have to remove window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION** from the production bundle, otherwise users on safari will have a crashing app...

Now I decided to finally google a little and here is what I found: https://medium.com/@zalmoxis/improve-your-development-workflow-with-redux-devtools-extension-f0379227ff83

> Instead of window.devToolsExtension (which was planned to be
>   deprecated in favour of window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION**), now
>   we’ll be using window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE**:

So I changed my code from:

```
  const createStoreWithFirebase = compose(
    reactReduxFirebase(fire, rrfConfig), // firebase instance as first argument
    reduxFirestore(fire),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )(createStore)
```

to:

```
  const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

  const createStoreWithFirebase = composeEnhancers(
    reactReduxFirebase(fire, rrfConfig), // firebase instance as first argument
    reduxFirestore(fire)
  )(createStore)
```

and now it works.